# Silverlight video: Chrome vs. Internet Explorer

Tags: html, silverlight, internet-explorer, google-chrome, video

In my Web application I need to play some videos using Silverlight video player. The videos need to start playing from a dynamically determined time. The issue I am having is that in Chrome the seek time is very long, quite often on the order of 20 seconds or more depending on how far I seek on the video, while in Internet Explorer the seek time is much faster, quite often about 2-3 seconds and it doesn't seem to depend on how far from the current position I seek.

The videos are served by IIS 7. Most of the videos are mp4 but unfortunately there are some in wmv format; that's why I have to use Silverlight. The seek time doesn't seem to depend on the video format. Silverlight version is  5.1.30214.0.

For the mp4 videos I tried playing them in Chrome using html5 video tag and the seek time is much better compared to Silverlight. Unfortunately as I said I have to use Silverlight.

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps exactly and that should fix your problem:

1. Make sure you are running a Silverlight-compatible Windows operating system and browser and that you have uninstalled any previous version of Silverlight.
2. Download Silverlight

For Windows Internet Explorer users:

The browser will prompt you to either run or save the installation file (Silverlight.exe). Click Run to start the download. When the download is finished, the browser prompts you again to run the installer. Click Run to start the installation. Note that you must have sufficient administrative privileges to install Silverlight (5.1.30214.0).

1. Install Silverlight

If you are running the Windows Vista operating system, you will be prompted for security permissions. To continue, you need to approve.

Click 'Install now' after reviewing the license agreement and privacy statement.

If you have had a previous version of Silverlight installed, or are using Mozilla Firefox, you will need to restart your browser.

1. Verify your installation by experiencing the Silverlight site.

For installation support, visit our [support](http://support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx?rdpath=1&gprid=12929) page.

Source: [Microsoft Silverlight Website](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx)

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking far. I have Silverlight installed and I can play videos in Chrome. But they don't fast forward nearly as fast as in Internet Explorer. That's my problem.